# Can't login to https sever via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a userscript with jquery, which calls https requests on a http webpage to login a forum.
But now I met a cookies problem: the cookies could not be set via ajax requests.

Here two images show the difference between traditional login and ajax login:

Traditional one:

1. Post username and password and get set-cookie
2. Send cookies to server to gain access to some webpage
   [image: traditional login]

Ajax one:

1. Use `$.post()` to post username and password, and get set-cookie
2. Not sending cookies to server

[image: ajax login]

And here I post my greasemonkey userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           test
// @namespace      test
// @description    test
// @include        http://solidot.org/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
//after events dealing and blahblahblah
$.post('https://bbs6.sjtu.edu.cn/bbslogin',{id:'some',pw:'password'});
$.post('https://bbs6.sjtu.edu.cn/bbssnd',{board:'SJTUNews',title:'some',text:'article'});
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to set the cookies ..

Comment: @Hristo OK, I post the main part of my script. The rest parts are about events binding and I don't think they are relevant.

Comment: @ManseUK I don't use js to set cookies, `cuz I don't think jquery can access cookies of another https domain on a http webpage.

Comment: Could you please check if the cookie even exists after the request was made?

Comment: @silvinci No, seems like firefox ignores crossdomian https ajax requests' `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: @Rufus please try using the built in [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) which ignores the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your login is on http: and your website to post to is on https:, you're dealing with cross-site-scripting limitations built into the browser and into jquery. I've run into similar issues when using jquery to a web service on the same server, but different port (which you're trying to do as well).

Some options:
- do the post by a normal form button
- move the jquery to https domain (which would require https access prior to login; this gives secure password transmission, yet you'll have to block access to content separately from https access)
- use some server side script to bridge the gap. I found http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/ to be very useful.

To diagnose the issue (to check if my hypothesis is right), you may use the web console built into Firefox (I prefer FireBug), or an optional developers package for Chrome.

Look at the console; check the post command. Note the domain/port your post is going to. I expect that the domain/port info is stripped from the post.

Another option: [Cross domain with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/). But please be careful: when allowing cross domain, take care not to open the back door for just any other domain!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, a reasonable answer finally showed up, I almost gave up hope.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the acknowledgement; I've been through the struggle myself before I saw the light (that different ports on the same machine are also cross-domain)

Answer (score 1):

@adriaan answered this directly and I gave him a point for that.

You cannot do this via AJAX.

You can try the following to simulate:

- if not postMessage browser support then post directly to the login page via https or use iframe hash change polling technique.
- if postMessage browser support then you can have cross domain communication supported natively via JavaScript across iframe so you can post the forms action to the iframe.
- this may be a moot point because people are suspect of the current URL is not HTTPS in the first place

I think it's preferable to redirect to HTTPS from a customer trust level on the perception of the website's security similarly how forced HTTPS occurs on exommerce.

See KitGUI.com for an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is but I think I know how to fix.

The thing is that you don't need to set a cookie with php you can also set it with JavaScript.

```
var login = $.post('https://bbs6.sjtu.edu.cn/bbslogin', {id: 'some', pw: 'password'})
    .success(function() {
        if (login.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie") != null)
            /**
             * Normally this returns a string but if not just do it with each value of the array
             */
            document.cookie = login.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
        else
            alert("Login failed");
    })
    .error(function() {
            alert("Login failed");
    });
```

If this doesn't work it could also be that you fire the second ajax request to fast, so try to change this to this:

```
$.post('https://bbs6.sjtu.edu.cn/bbslogin', {id: 'some', pw: 'password'})
        .success(function() {
                $.post('https://bbs6.sjtu.edu.cn/bbssnd', board:'SJTUNews',title:'some',text:'article'}); 
        });
```

Comment: Still can't do it, I guess it has something to do with browser's policy. I will ask mozilla for help.